# How to version-control different features within one web application?

Tags: php, architecture, system, upgrade

We have some web applications, and now these websites are being upgraded, not for the first time, but it is becoming very dificult to control the version for the users and for the developers.

We have many clients, some of they are running the same application, but they need to pay for upgrades. But, not all clients pay for upgrades, and because this we have some clients running one version and another clients running another version.

We have two ways, and we are researching for a third way:

1. Put the version in the path, like this: `www\project\version\system-files`

But this way became confusing for some users, because for they the URL became: `www.website.com/app-version`, and when the system is upgraded, the URL change.

2. Put the version in the function, like this: `function V1_functionX()`

When the function need to be upgraded, we create a new function called `V2_functionX`. But, this create a "fat" website, and the team did some mistakes during development, because we don't have "one development version", but "many versions to develop", and some functions are used in more than one website.

The very first way was abandoned a long time ago. We developed the web application, and "closed the version", and all requests was included in the upgraded version, that version when finished was "closed" too. But this was too slow too made corrections and deploy "small upgrades"

We talked about the way in another companies: they "shutdown" the website to upgrade the system. This will be probably our way.

But, if anyone have another idea to not shutdown a website for upgrade the application, we will be glad to listen.

Note: this is not about SVN.

Comment: Are you looking to maintain several live versions at the same time (perhaps for different customers)? Or is this just about creating different feature branches in your VCS?

Comment: Functions called `V1_functionX()` are a big warning indicator that something has gone wrong with the development approach, in my opinion. Can you expand on why you have "many versions to develop"?

Comment: You have another question about not shutting down the website when it is being upgraded - is that related? It is possible, yes - broadly you "build" the website elsewhere on the server and the run a script to amend a symlink. Or you can modify the vhost definition in the build process and then graceful restart the webserver. But that probably deserves its own question, since it is a big topic.

Comment: You should be using a VCS such as GIT... each site could have its own repository and could "pull" from a master repository:branch.. What you are doing now is seriously flawed and will make for nearly impossible management and headaches.

Comment: thanks for your comments. We have some concerns in our team, and this subject is becoming very problematic. We have many clients, running different versions of our applications.

Comment: @HalfCrazed, thanks for your comment. The use of VCS is not the problem. The problem is maintain VCS and Website Applcations through many customers. If we had only one application version running it will be easy, but we have many versions of the same application running.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You say you have different versions of your applications that must be maintained for different clients. I expect you don't need me to tell you this adds significantly to the complexity of your overall system, and thus your first priority is to reduce the number of versions you are maintaining in parallel.

API services have the same problem: a new version with more features is offered, but the old one needs to be maintained to give the new version time to stabilise and to give users sufficient time to upgrade their code. Your difficulty is similar. The first question I would therefore ask is whether it is possible to maintain only two versions.

If that is not possible, try at least minimising the number of concurrent versions: where a new version must be created, you need to encourage users to migrate from one version to another. (You've said you cannot unify your users onto one version, but without further information about your exact use-case, it is not possible to offer an independent view on that). So, perhaps one approach is to never maintain more than, say, five versions.

There are a number of strategies you can take to mitigate the complexity of the system you now have. Firstly, consider separating your code into a "core" of features that all versions absolutely must have. This will be common to all versions, so that if you fix a bug here, all clients benefit from the fix. This might be a visible feature (e.g. a product editing screen) or a framework feature (e.g. force SSL during checkout).

Your core libraries and client-specific functions could then reside in a set of libraries like so:

```
/project/core
/project/versions/1/Class.php
/project/versions/1.1/Class.php
/project/versions/2/Class.php
/project/versions/2.1.1/Class.php
/project/versions/...
```

*(`Class.php` is of course an example - in practise there would be many class files here, each named appropriately.)*

In this way, you do not need to call functions with a `V1_` prefix, since that will require the replication of your version choosing code in a lot of places. It is much better to just load the library pertaining to the correct version, and as long as the function names are the same across all versions, you can just use the function name and your library loader will take care of the rest.

Another approach is to use plugins, like WordPress does. Where a plugin is added, it modifies some core functionality by adding new or different behaviour. The "middleware" design pattern may be useful here - the Slim framework (and undoubtedly others) uses this approach to add pre- or post-call hooks to an existing route handler, and thus offers a clean mechanism to edit existing functionality in a variety of combinations.

To summarise, your current situation is not just a management problem, but will cost you in slow development time and additional debugging. Whilst the above approaches will still be necessary to reduce some of the complexity, consider also:

- forcing laggard clients to upgrade to one of your currently supported versions
- giving an upgrade to laggard clients to the oldest possible supported version for free

---

Some additional thoughts based on new information. I had pondered whether splitting the code into separate repositories would help, one for each client. However I wonder if there is no guarantee that they would; even if you pull core features in using Composer, or a Git submodule, there is still the possibility of divergence between your latest core and your earliest client code. At some point your worst laggard client is going to hold back development on the core.

You can always leave this client on an abandoned version, but if they spot a bug, it is not worth back-porting a fix from your latest core, since that will cause you all the compatibility headaches you've been trying to avoid. Either they upgrade to a minimum client version that works with the latest core (and pay to do so if necessary) or they tolerate the bug indefinitely.

You've mentioned that each client gets his or her own database. That is helpful, up to a point, since it means that client versions are not entirely constrained with database schema decisions that have been forced by the core. However, this will still have a knock-on effect on how much code you can move to the core.

For example, let us assume that you have seven clients, and six of them have a User entity that has an email address, to handle password change requests (one client has a User entity without this field). This means that, if the awkward schema may not change, the core cannot assume that an email address is available. (In this trivial case it might be cheaper to upgrade the odd-one-out for free, so that more code can go in the core, rather than maintaining such a standard thing as a version enhancement).

Given the level of complexity, and since it sounds like you are maintaining this for the long term, I think you should set up some unit and functional tests. You'll need to split these into "core" and "per version" as well. If you find a bug, regardless of whether it is caused by feature versioning or not, write a failing test, and then fix it. You'll then have - at least in theory - a way to check if a change will impact on a particular client's version in a way you did not envisage.

Comment: Additional questions I might reply to in my answer, for the OP: I take it your code is all in one repository? Do you maintain separate databases for each client or each version, or is everyone on one database?

Comment: thanks for your answer. I will read again tomorrow (it is 22h30m in Brazil), but I liked what you said "consider separating your code into a "core" of features".

Comment: the code is in one repository, local server. each client has his own database.

Comment: No problem @Ricardo. I've added a few more thoughts.

Answer (score 0):

We have this at my work :

1. Local dev website(SVN)
2. dev server where all developer test
3. Preprod where everything is Ok
4. Prod (rsync from preprod)

The rsync between 2 server is super fast, when we do a major update its in less than 5s

Comment: Thanks, but the problem is not "how to update the server", but "how to name the application and project to avoid conflict"

Comment: And, another problem, how to deal with different customers running different versions of same application.

Comment: Ok, so I think they're not a good answer, what you describe v1_function,v2_function is more a question of a right or an option in you're app but you its not another version of you're app, it's like a package, when I add a new package I don't reinstall my Debian